# How do I install a CA bundle on Laravel Forge?

Tags: nginx, laravel-forge

I've got an application that's getting SSL warnings on Chrome for Android and it turns out I need to add my CA Bundle from RapidSSL. I don't see a way to do this using Laravel Forge. How can I accomplish this?

My nginx config was auto-generated by Laravel Forge and looks like this:

```
# FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.com/1646/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mydomain.com/1646/server.key;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I solved this problem by doing the following:

1. Download the RapidSSL CA bundle:

https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=AR1549

2. Paste it below my certificate in a text file.

https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pem-ssl-creation.htm

3. Pasted the three certs in one into Laravel forge when it asks for my certificate.

And it worked!

Answer (score 7):

## Status before: untrusted page

I had the same issue with a comodo certificate from https://cheapsslsecurity.com/. At first I installed only the domain specific certificate via the laravel forge webinterface (www_timtimer_at.crt) which resulted in an untrusted page.

Stumbling upon the answer of @Citizen and the post [Nginx not serving intermediate certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25109349/nginx-not-serving-intermediate-certificate) helped me to fix it. See this post also for debugging instructions.

## How to fix the problem

### SSL-Status

Use `openssl s_client -connect www.timtimer.at:443` to check the certificate chain. (As am I am using Windows I just used the git bash to use this command). It should be a real chain like the following (s=subject, i=issuer). So you always have a subject with an issuer. This issuer should be the next subject which is issued by another authority and so on. The last subject is itselfs issuer.

At first my **certificate chain** looked like the following:

> **Certificate chain**
>    **0** s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=www.timtimer.at
>     i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA

The **Verify return code** was: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate).

### Solution

Check your server configuration file (I am using Laravel forge with nginx, so my file would be */etc/nginx/sites-available/default* to get the location of the certificate you are using. Look out for the following section

```
# FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/default/2658/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/default/2658/server.key;
```

So in my case the certificate is stored in */etc/nginx/ssl/default/2658/server.crt*. Now edit this file and make sure you put all the needed certificates in there. I added the content of the certificates from the zip-file in the following order:

1. www_timtimer_at.crt
2. COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
3. COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
4. AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt

The file should look like like the following

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (www_timtimer_at.crt)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

After a `/etc/init.d/nginx restart` everything looked good.

I received the following **certificate chain** after executing `openssl s_client -connect www.timtimer.at:443`:

> **Certificate chain**
>    **0** s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=www.timtimer.at
>      i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
>    **1** s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
>      i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
>    **2** s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
>      i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
>    **3** s:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
>      i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root

The **Verify return code** was: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain).

Comment: I'm by no means a SSL expert, but https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest will return warnings if you include the `AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt` certificate. No issues when you leave it out.